# Pre-transmission burst sent by fldigi

Tags: digital-modes, fldigi

Every time I click on a PSK macro, before transmitting the message, fldigi outputs a burst of something for about a second.  This is visible but not readable on my waterfall display. It wastes time and I want to get rid of it.

Comment: Is your TX ID on?

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  We recommend that new users take [the tour](http://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) to get the most from the site.

Comment: I see that you have asked several questions related to fldigi. You might benefit from the collected wisdom of the Winfldigi community on groups.io.

Answer (score 5):

That's a [Reed-Solomon identification](http://www.w1hkj.com/RSID_description.html) (RSID). It's purpose is to tell other stations what mode you are using. For PSK it's usually pretty obvious.

To disable it, look for the "TxID" button in the upper-right of the window, and click it to toggle it on and off.

(As you might imagine, the RxID button toggles the receiving of RSIDs. When it is enabled, Fldigi will tune the receiver and switch to the correct mode automatically when it hears one.)

[image]

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: But please do not disable it. The RSID is very, very useful.

Without the RSID, people don't know which digital mode you are using, so they can't answer you.

Comment: PSK31 is by now about as established as RTTY, CW, and SSB, and no one identifies those. Since the RSID bandwidth is significantly more than PSK31 it causes a lot of interference with adjacent stations, to transmit information that's obvious to almost everyone anyway. Please do turn it off unless you are utilizing some other digital mode.